# Batch file with mogrify into folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, imagemagick

I can shrink some images with imagemagick using mogrify in a batch file but I'm having trouble setting the destination directory

```
@ECHO OFF
SET scriptdir=%~dp0
cd /d %imagedir%
SET tb="thumbs"
IF NOT EXIST "%imagedir%"/%tb% MKDIR "%imagedir%"/%tb%
FOR %%a in (*.tif) do (
mogrify -resize 42x42 -format jpg -quality 100  %%a
move %%a %imagedir%/%tb%
)
```

The above script does what I want, but it's bugging me that I have to use move command to place the images there instead of creating them there.

Comment: Since you are using a Batch file, I assume you are on Windows.  But you have written all your paths to use ForwardSlash.  Windows uses BackSlash to separate paths.

Comment: I am running Win 7 which does allow bi-directional slashes or so it would seem cd /windows --> C:\windows>

Comment: That doesn't mean it is correct or that a Win32 build of Mogrify will accept improper slashes.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `-path XYZ` into your `mogrify` command to get **ImageMagick** to write the output files in directory `XYZ`. For example:

```
mkdir results
mogrify -path results -resize ... inputfile.jpg
```

The whole point of `mogrify` though is that *you don't need a loop*, you just do all the files in one go:

```
mogrify -path results -format jpg -resize 42x42 *.tif
```

Comment: FOR %%a in (*.tif) do (mogrify -path thumbs -resize 42x42 -format jpg -quality 100  %%a) doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Did you create the `thumbs` subdirectory first? Also, what version are you using?

Comment: Create directory first check. ImageMagick version 6.9.3

Comment: Please try with just a single file. i.e. not in a `FOR` loop and also not in a BATCH script, just type it in for one file to make sure it works.

Comment: And that works without the loop - thanks for the headsup. - although the images are very small (see your deliberate typo)

Answer (score 0):

Use option `-write filename`, documented as: `write images to this file`

```
mogrify -resize 42x42 -format jpg -quality 100 -write %imagedir%\%tb%\%%a %%a
```

I used `%imagedir%\%tb%\%%a` to fully specify an output filename, and I changed the slashes to Backslashes.

Comment: mogrify.exe: unable to open image `/thumbs': Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702.

Comment: Why are you using forward slashes (`/`) with Batch files and Windows, which uses backslashes (`\\`)?

Comment: Forward slashes tend to work fine pretty much everywhere in my experience, going back to early DOS 2.x days.